# How to add an icon to c++ application using Digital Mars compiler (rcc.exe and dmc.exe)

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, resources, icons

I am working on a project in which I must use Digital Mars c++ compiler. I need to add an icon to my `.exe` file. I know how to add an icon on Visual Studio but it is not the case because I am working on Digital Mars (I need step by step command line guide to add the icon which I assume VS does in the background). My project contains a resource file as `Hello.rc` :

```
#include "resource.h"

MAINICON ICON "icon.ico"
MY_RESOURCE RCDATA "a.txt"
```

A resource header file as `resource.h`:

```
#define MAINICON      101    
#define RCDATA    256
#define ICON    257
#define MY_RESOURCE 300
```

And a main file as `Hello.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

void LoadFileInResource(int name, int type, DWORD& size, const char*& data)
{
    HMODULE handle = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRSRC rc = ::FindResource(handle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(name),
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(type));
    HGLOBAL rcData = ::LoadResource(handle, rc);
    size = ::SizeofResource(handle, rc);
    data = static_cast<const char*>(::LockResource(rcData));
}

// Usage example
int main()
{
    DWORD size = 0;
    const char* data = NULL;
    LoadFileInResource(MY_RESOURCE, RCDATA, size, data);    
    char snum[5];

    // convert 123 to string [buf]
    itoa(size, snum, 10);

    // print our string
    printf("%s\n", snum);
    /* Access bytes in data - here's a simple example involving text output*/
    // The text stored in the resource might not be NULL terminated.
    char* buffer = new char[size+1];    
    ::memcpy(buffer, data, size);
    buffer[size] = 0; // NULL terminator
    ::printf("Contents of text file: %s\n", buffer); // Print as ASCII text
    delete[] buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile my project using the following commands. Resulting `.exe` can read the content of `a.txt` but does not show any icon.

```
rcc hello.rc
dmc hello.cpp hello.rc
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or should I use a different command?

Comment: Not sure, maybe this helps: https://www.digitalmars.com/faq.html#classexpress

Comment: Also [here's](https://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/sc.html) some reference to Digital Mars' resource compiler. You probably need to study in more depth at their documentation which seems to be pretty complete.

Comment: I studied the parts related to `rcc.exe` but I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: I am not using `rc.exe`, I use `rcc.exe` which is the resource compiler of Digital mars. I am not able to change my resource compiler too (because of size limitations, dm compiler is very lightweight).

Comment: `ICON` and `RCDATA` are standard resource types, they should not be redefined. Resource compiler should recognize `ICON`. Remove `#define ICON 257`. Put `1 ICON "icon.ico"` in resource file, compile and link. Note that Windows will cache the icon for each file, so you won't know if you succeeded until you restart the system and icon cache is clear. You can also copy/paste the *.exe file with a different name to fool the system so it won't use the same cache for that file.

Comment: You can also use `HICON hicon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(1))` to test for success. `hicon` should be non-NULL.

Comment: Thank you so much @BarmakShemirani It solved my problem but I found out that in digital mars compiler I have to use Windows 3.0 icons (16 colors ). Is there any way to be able to use win32 model icons (True color) in digital mars.

Comment: I am not familiar with that compiler. Use `-32` option for 32-bit resource - [see link](https://digitalmars.com/ctg/rcc.html). Is your *.exe output 16-bit or 32-bit? If it's 32-bit, try it 256 color icon (remember changes to icon may not show until restart).